# Anypoint Studio - Where in the world is runtime 3.8.2?

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

I'm working on a Mule ESB (enterprise edition) project.

to install new verisons of the runtime into Anypoint Studio, you are suppose to just go to :

> Help > install New Software...

then search for the correct runtime. I thought every run time was suppose to be findable via

> Mule Runtimes for Anypoint Studio - http://studio.mulesoft.org/r5/studio-runtimes/

however, runtime 3.8.3 is not in this repository, nor is 3.8.2, which is the version I **want** to use since that is the latest version cloudhub hosts.

**net-net:** mule runtime version 3.8.2 is nowhere to be found, yet mule cloudhub reallly wants me to use this version of the run time.

Where in the world is verison 3.8.2???

*update* Below is screenshot of the runtimes as I seem them looking at the studio-runtimes, and the filter criteria I used. as you can see, the only 3.8 versions are 3.8.0 and 3.8.1, no 3.8.2:

[image: studio-runtimes]

Comment: Its strange, yesterday I haven't seen under `r5 studio runtime`. Today I can able to see 3.8.2EE under  `r5 studio runtime`. First check for updates and then see in software Updates. This is the steps i followed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3.8.2 has been reposted.....................................

[image]

Comment: I am still not seeing it in the list. just checked... I am running Version: 6.1.1, of anypoint studio would that affect what I am seeing?

Comment: Checked this again today, and 3.8.2 is now appearing. thank you!

Answer (score -1):

[image]
see screen shot. You'll see that the very latest runtime is available under studio's updates. if you still don't see it make sure you uncheck the "hide items that are already installed"

Comment: yeah, your screenshot looks exactly like mine did, I only see 3.8.3. I'll update my question with a screenshot of how I am not seeing 3.8.2

Comment: sorry, downvoting becaue screentshot does not cover 3.8.2

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure that you have not 3.8.2 EE installed?
I expect that you do not :)

Have you checked for updates?? The repository indexes you have might be outdated. Check for updates "Help"->"Check For Updates"

The latest runtime is found in a different repository:
Anypoint Studio Update Site - http://studio.mulesoft.org/r5/updates

The non-latest versions are found in:
Mule Runtimes for Anypoint Studio - http://studio.mulesoft.org/r5/studio-runtimes/

So to solve your problem try this:

1. Make sure the version you are looking for is not all ready installed
2. Check for updates "Help"->"Check For Updates"
3. Look for the runtime in the "Anypoint Studio Update Site"
4. Look for the runtime in the "Mule Runtimes for Anypoint Studio"

I hope this will help

Comment: yes, 1 am 100% confident I do not have 3.8.2 installed. I have included a screenshot of my search of the studio-runtimes to help clarify this issue.